Is `static const` ever better/required from perspective of correctness/UB compared to just `static`?
For example, I was writing an enum→string function.
static const char *fooname(enum Foo f) {
        /* assumes f is a valid Foo enum */
        static const char *names[] = {
                [FOO1]="a foo", [FOO2]="another foo", [FOO3]="foo the third",
        };
        return names[f];
}

My understanding of static: a) it restricts scope vs declaring a global names[] b) it is required otherwise the pointer returned would point to a stack variable. But while I have put const, I'm not sure if it is necessary to declared names as static const to prevent any UB/ for correctness here.
To give another case, which involves simple integers instead:
int myfn(int i) {
        /* assumes i is a valid index*/
        static const int map[] = {24, 45, 56};
        return map[i];
}

Here, I have used static as we don't need to create map anew each time.
My main question is this I guess: from what I understand, writing variables as const is more of a stylistic concern, but if one prefers not to use const, is it required in these special cases with static, or optional like in most other cases? (I know that for parameters to pointers, we should definitely declare const).

The array doesn't need to be static, but without that the compiler is free to populate a new array with every function call if it wants to. If it's non-static, it's still fine to return the value names[f] which is a string literal that itself has static storage. That's not a pointer to a stack variable -- it's a pointer value. In general, even in a very simple function, if you have a table that should not be modified, then it's useful to declare that intent by using const. In fact, static const char * const names[] would be appropriate in that case.

Oh, I see, thank you @paddy it seems I had a few misconceptions. So, to clarify, a) it is always okay to return a char* from a function if all paths are just returning literals (No UB). And b) in the names example here (and generally) const only serves to document intent (and maybe optimisations in a few cases).

const does not only document intent, but actively prevents you from breaking that contract, because the compiler emits an error if you try (including accidentally doing it). Specifically with regards to string literals, it's a good habit to use const char* because that provides additional information: "this string is not modifiable". There are other cases beyond string literals where you can return a pointer. The real rule is that whatever it points to should still be a live object. If it's pointing to something that was since popped off the stack, that's where you run into trouble.

@You'reNotARobot - A reason for the fuzzy rules about string literals is that initially (in the 1970s) C didn't have a const keyword. So they used char* to point to a string literal (even when it really was a constant). Not much reason to follow that example anymore.

Neither const is a top level const, so it makes no sense to think of static const as a unit here.
What I mean by that: even though static and const appear next to each other, the types of the variables are:

names is a static array of mutable pointers to const chars
map is a static array of const integers.

So neither variable is a static const variable. (arrays are not mutable, but the word const in here has nothing to do with that).
These would be examples of static const variables (where const is top level):

static const int a = 12; (static constant int)
static int * const p = /* ... */; (static constant pointer to int type)

const does not influence the UB status of a static variable (unless it would have influenced it anyway if the variable would have been non static in the first place).
From your comments:


I see. So if all I want is the table to not be created freshly each time/ be in read only memory, all I need is the static, and all of the other consting has no effect?

You conflating two different things: when a variable is created/initialized and if it's created in a read only memory.
static affects the storage duration (i.e. when a variable is created and released), while const affects the latter. const does not affect storage duration.
void foo()
{
    int a = 24; // automatic storage duration, mutable
    int const b = 24; // automatic storage duration, const
   
    static int c = 24; // static storage duration,
                       // mutable (cannot be allocated in read only memory (*))

    static const int d = 24; // static storage duration,
                             // const (can be allocated in read only memory (*))
}

*) except that the as-if rule allows the compiler to generate any code and allocate anywhere as long as the observable effects of the execution of the program are the same. E.g.:

for c iff the compiler can prove that c is not and can never be legally changed then it can put it in read-only memory
for d the compiler can never allocate memory for it (it can be encoded in the hardware instructions of the operations using it).


I see. So if all I want is the table to not be created freshly each time/ be in read only memory, all I need is the static, and all of the other consting has no effect?

@You'reNotARobot not quite. See edit.

Great answer, thank you @bolov

In this specific case:
    static const char *names[] = {
            [FOO1]="a foo", [FOO2]="another foo", [FOO3]="foo the third",
    };

Defining names as an array of const char * makes sense since you're assigning the starting address of string literals to each element and string literals are read only (although not const for historic reasons).
In general however, there's no specific reason static variables need to be declared as const.  In particular, given your second example, there's no benefit to declaring map as const.

So sorry about that, I have fixed the second example. And thank you for your answer. In the updated second example then, there is no reason/need to use const?

@You'reNotARobot You're misunderstanding const. In the first example, the const is bound to what the pointer points to, not the pointer value itself. For that, you'd use const char * const names[] -- then it would be more comparable to your const int names[] example.
